# Line charts not working properly in PowerPoint in v2.1.0 of PptxGenJS

Tags: javascript, pptxgenjs

I'm trying to generate a pptx file with charts but there is an error while opening the generated file in Power Point when there is some 'chart.LINE'. Charts with '.BAR' type are rendered normally, like texts and images.

The same file opens perfectly in Keynote and in Libre Office. That's just in Power Point, and it occurs in any version (I'm using Microsoft Office 2016).
I am working with latest version of PptxGenJS (v2.1.0) and nothing goes wrong during export. I mean that the code runs normally, without erros or warnings and the file is exported. The problem occurs while trying to open.

The error messages in Power Point are:
[PowerPoint could not read content and removed it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZTiB.png) / [Power Point may try to repair the presentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gp923.png) / [Power Point failed to repair content and removed it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hImMP.png)

Basically a default message informing that was not possible to read some content and by trying to repair, it has been removed.

Note: By opening the file in Keynote or Google Slides and then saving/exporting as ‘pptx' it works. All charts are rendered normally.

[Expected result - Only occurs in Keynote or Google Slides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgxk5.png)

I don’t know what’s going on due to the lack of explicit errors and if someone could help me I would appreciate.

Thank you.

Comment: Please include the error messages in english so everyone can read them.

Answer (score 0):

Is the PowerPoint version you are using 32 bit?
Maybe the framework is exporting 64-bit components, and your PowerPoint is 32.
That would explain the error message at the beginning.