# PptxGenJS add chart show nothing

Tags: reactjs, pptxgenjs

I am working with an export function by using [PptxGenJS](https://gitbrent.github.io/PptxGenJS/). It does not work **even with basic example code from demo source code on official Github**. I am working with export charts.

My steps:

- Install PptxGenJS and import like normal npm package.
- Copy code from [official demo](https://github.com/gitbrent/PptxGenJS/blob/master/demos/common/demos.js):
  `slide.addChart( pptx.charts.BAR, arrDataRegions, optsChartBar1 );`

The result:

- Chart show nothing in exported slider.
- Open with Microsoft Powerpoint 2013, it shows some error similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49819105/line-charts-not-working-properly-in-powerpoint-in-v2-1-0-of-pptxgenjs).
- [My codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pptxgenjs-chart-show-nothing-0tygp?file=/src/App.js) even worse, no file were downloaded.

My notable package versions:

```
"react": "^16.13.1",
"pptxgenjs": "^2.6.0",
```

My environment versions:

- node version: `v10.17.0`
- npm version: `v6.11.3`
- Windows 10 Pro 1903, OS build `18362.1082`

Both two versions of `Pptxgenjs` do not work.
Any thoughts on this? Thanks for any idea. I'm giving up on this library.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe case-sensitive. Change your BAR to bar like below,

```
import pptxgen from "pptxgenjs";

let pres = new pptxgen();
let slide = pres.addSlide();
let dataChartAreaLine = [
            {
                name: "Actual Sales",
                labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"],
                values: [1500, 4600, 5156, 3167, 8510, 8009],
            },
            {
                name: "Projected Sales",
                labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"],
                values: [1000, 2600, 3456, 4567, 5010, 6009],
            },
        ];

        slide.addChart(pres.ChartType.bar, dataChartAreaLine, { x: 2, y: 2, w: 6, h: 3, showLegend: true });

pres.writeFile("Sample Presentation.pptx");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is now I am not continued that project anymore :)) don't have time to confirm again.